# PHP str_replace() with multiple parameter on condition

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use php str_replace() function on some condition.
Eg : if the string has `am`  i want to replace with `:00` and if it has `pm` i want to replace with `:00`. There will be one `am` or `pm` on the string and I want to replace with same variable. How do I do it using PHP?

```
 $classRoom->start =Carbon::parse($request->input('start'));
dd(str_replace(array('am', ':00'), array('pm', ':00'),$request->input('start')));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str_replace(array('am', 'pm'), ':00', $request->input('start'));
```

You can pass an array to both of the first parameters for str_replace. You need to pass an array of the text to search for. Then you pass an array or string of things to replace.